# determine composer sub dependencies

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, composer-php

I am running update on composer and one of the dependancies defined in my composer.json is trying to pull a sub dependency from repo that no longer exists (very annoying!)

How can I determine which of the modules is defining the required library, verbose output and dry run don't really give much indication

my list is :

```
"php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*",

    "doctrine/doctrine-module": "0.8.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.8.*@dev",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",
    "hounddog/doctrine-data-fixture-module":"0.0.*",

    "zf-commons/zfc-admin": ">=0.1.1",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": ">=0.1.1",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": ">=0.1.1",
    "zf-commons/zfc-base": "v0.1.2",

    "danielss89/zfc-user-admin": "dev-master",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize":"1.4.*",
    "zf-hipsters/bootstrap-flash-messenger": ">=1.0",
    "spoonx/sxbootstrap": "3.*",
    "manuakasam/sam-versioning" : "dev-master",
    "neilime/zf2-twb-bundle": "2.0",
    "rwoverdijk/assetmanager": "1.*",
    "imagine/imagine": "0.6.*@dev",
    "tawfekov/zf2entityaudit": ">=0.2-stable",
    "evandotpro/edp-superluminal": "dev-master",
    "netglue/zf2-route-layout-module": "dev-master",
    "twbs/bootstrap":"3.*",
```

The missing library that has suddenly started causing issues is `backplane\zendframework`

Comment: We have the same problem. If I know more I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks, I believe it might be related to doctrine or a dependency of doctrine but hard to determine.

Comment: We are using Doctrine as well, so it is a suspect ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As user1786423 has pointed, it is problem of getting zendframework 2.2* and doctrine 0.8.* together.

What i did was i have upgraded to zf 2.3.* like this:

```
"php": ">=5.3.3",
"zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
"doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*"
```

Then `composer update` and everything goes ok.

```
- Updating zendframework/zendframework (dev-master 6f2d379 => dev-develop 4d8a7eb)
    Checking out 4d8a7ebdf3f628b10b9bfbf48babfaa3f903842b
- Updating doctrine/common (2.4.x-dev c94d6ff => dev-master 64e2a6a)
    Checking out 64e2a6ae51db05a1ea0525913ed0dcccdc523f01
```

etc.

Then i needed to handle one more dependency conflict, specific for my configuration.

Comment: I had the same problem, bumping up the version number actually helped. This is kinda sad that having a fixed and locked dependencies can break the building process. I'm sad.

Answer (score 2):

backplane/zendframework was fork of zf2 which was later removed, it defined composer package "replacing" zf2 and might show when your dependencies are not satisfiable - composer tries some alternatives and finds this - in cases we met, there was someone asking for zf2.2.* and at the same time doctrine-(orm-)module 0.9.*@dev because doctrine module curently requires zf2.3

You use zf2.2.* and doctrine module 0.8.*@dev so it is some other subdependency.

```
php composer.phar depends doctrine/doctrine-module
```

and check versions.

For sure backplane/zendframework is not direct sub-dependency anywhere, problem is in version mismatch and composer finding alternative - there is filled [issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2690)

Comment: I changed the required versions of both and the issue went away but the same problem with other dependancies not satisfied. I rolled back to the previous versions and it appears that the issue is no longer present. I assume that the sub dependency has been removed from where ever it was

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can do;

`composer depends backplane\zendframework`

But it seems that this is a dependency of another dependency and Composer won't show which one... The only solution is recursively analyzing the dependencies by hand...?!

Comment: Yea i started going down this route but its a painful process. :(